# I have defined a function to rank schools by the sat_score criteria, but this function doesn't work

Tags: python

```
def score(school):
    school = combined['SCHOOL NAME']    
    for row in school:
        schools = combined[combined['SCHOOL NAME'] == row]
        if schools['sat_score'].iloc[0]>= 1500.0:
            return 'high score'
        elif (schools['sat_score'].iloc[0] > 1100.0) & (schools['sat_score'].iloc[0]< 1500.0):
            return 'medium_score'

        else:
            schools['sat_score'].iloc[0] <=1100.0
            return 'poor_score'  

combined['ranking_school'] = combined['sat_score'].apply(score)
```

This function yield only `'medium_score'` in all the numbers of the data series `combined['ranking_school']`. Instead, have to outcome the 3 possibilities that are: `high_score`, `medium_score`, and `poor_score`.
If someone could help with this, it will be so nice!!!
Regards

Comment: you appear to be using `&` ([bitwise 'AND'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types)) instead of the boolean operation [`and`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: I guess you want to use `and` instead of `&`. Also, what do you want to achieve with `schools['sat_score'].iloc[0] <=1100.0`? Where's `combined`?

Comment: Is `combined` a pandas data frame or a dictionary?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.
Your given code is not sufficient to reproduce the problem you describe, or the others lurking behind it.

Comment: combined is a data frame not a dictionary. Is a merge data frame, of 5 differents Data Frames. With the code: schools['sat_score'].iloc[0] <=1100.0, I want to select the float number of schools['sat_score] and compare to 1100.0. If the number is less than 1100.0 the value that the function return will be "low_score"

Comment: Do you need some additional information?

Comment: The aim of the function is to assign a score for each school based in the sat_score column of the combined data frame.

Comment: I have to use iloc[0] since if I put only schools['sat_score'], give the following error message: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().